# WCF Ria Services entities and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, inotifypropertychanged

I am having an issue where the *PropertyChanged* event from the generated Ria Services entities is not raised for all the properties.

When I look at the generated code (client-side), I can see that my entities are deriving from the *Entity* object which implements *INotifyPropertyChanged*. I can also see that some properties, like the *Id* property, is raising the *PropertyChanged* event but some are not.

I did not use any T4 templates so the default were used.

So, my question is:

Is there an option/attribute that I can set so that the *PropertyChanged* event be raised for any properties of the generated client-side entities?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's an example of a property, in the auto-generated **client-side** file, which **doesn't** raise the *PropertyChanged* event:

```
    [DataMember()]
    [Required()]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._firstName != value))
            {
                this.OnFirstNameChanging(value);
                this.RaiseDataMemberChanging("FirstName");
                this.ValidateProperty("FirstName", value);
                this._firstName = value;
                this.RaiseDataMemberChanged("FirstName");
                this.OnFirstNameChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is what was defined in the model **server-side**:

```
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return _FirstName;
        }
        set
        {
            OnFirstNameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("FirstName");
            _FirstName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            OnFirstNameChanged();
        }
    }
```

Here's an example of a property, in the auto-generated **client-side** file, which **does** raise the *PropertyChanged* event:

```
    [DataMember()]
    [Editable(false, AllowInitialValue=true)]
    [Key()]
    [RoundtripOriginal()]
    public Guid Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._id != value))
            {
                this.OnIdChanging(value);
                this.ValidateProperty("Id", value);
                this._id = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
                this.OnIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is what was defined in the model **server-side**:

```
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Guid Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_Id != value)
            {
                OnIdChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("Id");
                _Id = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("Id");
                OnIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which properties don´t raise the PropertyChanged event? Add some of your code to explain what you mean

Comment: Jehof, thanks for your reply. I just added some code as you requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **PropertyChanged** event is encapsulated in the **RaiseDataMemberChanged**(). You can check this with any Decompiler (.NET Reflector, etc.).

The RaiseDataMemberChanged and RaiseDataMemberChanging methods are used to notify the framework about changes for change tracking and state transitions.

These two properties are diffrent, cause the Id property is decorated with the Key-Attribute. I think properties with this attribute get special handling, due to associations with other entities, and a diffrent auto-generated implementation, cause there is not need to track changes or transistions on change.

So in your case, i think there is another problem, why your PropertyChanged event is (maybe) not fired.

Comment: You are right. The problem is elsewhere then. Thanks for you help!